# Python crawler can't open the page, but browser could open

Tags: python, web-crawler

I write a crawler to crawler many pages from a website, the open code is below:

```
def url_open(url):
    req = urllib.request.Request(headers=header, url=url)
    print('Getting content from {0}'.format(url))
    while True:
        try:
            response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
            break
        except:
            continue
    contents = response.read().decode('utf8')
    return contents
```

Sometimes the program will stop at print line, but still running. So I thought this page is bad, but I can open it in browser. And when I run my crawler again, this page could be open again.

Last time I used the same code to crawl another website, same problem occurred.

how do you write crawler to crawl many pages? And is this happened to you? How to handle it?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Can you print exception? 

Actually when you deal with network failures are quite often and there can be many reasons: network failure, temporary host unavailability, some hosts limit requests that you can send to them and if you are trying to get too many pages quickly they may respond with error.

Comment: alexxx, I'd recommend you use a more high-level library than urllib.request. For instance, use `requests` (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/). Right now, your code won't work for a number of reasons (HTTPS pages scrapped this way won't give be decodable; some pages like stackoverflow.com will return empty content, your exception is too broad, and combined with your `while True` loop, the script is very likely to run into infinite loops)

Comment: @HEADLESS_0NE Thank you very much, I will try this one.

Comment: OK, thank you, I'm learning how to print and handle it.

Comment: Hi.. I have the same error, How did you solve it ?

Comment: @rogoro, finally I found that may because I didn't close connection, and there are too many connections. And maybe another reason is that your connection requests to the website are too frequent, so the website has forbidden your IP within a while. if it is this reason, you may needs proxy.